# JavaMail content-transfer-encoding issue

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have some Java code which sends out an email with code somewhat like the following: Actually i got Mimemessage from Httprequest param and in that mimemessage i'm going to append some content to existing body.

If Mimemessage is of Multipart content-type , i'm not facing any issue while sending message.

If the message is of text/plain and text/html content-type, the content-transfer encoding which i set didn't applied to body.

Based on this [docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html)

Q: Even though JavaMail does all the encoding and decoding for me, I need to manually control the encoding for some body parts. A: In the rare case that you need to control the encoding, there are several ways to override JavaMail's default behavior. A simple approach is as follows. After creating the entire message, call msg.saveChanges() and then use something like mbp.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64") to force base64 encoding for the given body part.

Another approach is to subclass MimeBodyPart and override the updateHeaders method so that it first calls super.updateHeaders() and then sets the Content-Transfer-Encoding header as above.

Applied above also. But it doesn't works for me.

```
InputStream ins = request.getInputStream();
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session,ins);
msg.setContent("some non-Ascii content","text/plain; charset="UTF-8"");
//Tried setheader before saveChanges() method, also doesn't work for me
//msg.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","base64"); 
msg.saveChanges();
//Now tried based on above docs after saveChanges method, also doesn't work
msg.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","base64");
```

please help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You duplicated most of this question in your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493311/in-mimemessage-how-to-make-setcontent-method-should-also-change-value-returned-b), and I answered part of it there.

You would probably be better off sending the content for the mail message in the http request, then creating a new message on the server based on that content, instead of trying to send a complete MIME message to the server that you then edit.